# How can I get value from one table row using checkbox ( JSP & HTML )?

Tags: java, html, jsp

So, I'm using JSP to display in internet page data from database. I have two tables ( "Product Catalog" & "Invoices" ). I want to choose one product from table ( Product Catalog ) with help of **checkbox** and **insert into** another table ( Invoices ).

[image]

[image]

**productCatalog.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Product Catalog</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%

            String sql;
            String output;
            String table;
            ResultSet rs;
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/", "SA", "");

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_CATALOG");

            output = "<tr>" + "<th>SELECT PRODUCT</th>" + "<th>PRODUCT ID</th>" + "<th>PRODUCT NAME</th>" + "<th>PRICE</th></tr>";
            while (rs.next()) {
                output += "<tr><td><input type='checkbox'></td>" + "<td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td>" + "<td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td>" + "<td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td></tr>";
            }
            table = "<html>"
                    + "<head>"
                    + "</head>"
                    + "<body>"
                    + "<div>"
                    + "<h1>Product Catalog</h1>"
                    + "<form action='invoiceTable.jsp' method='POST'>"
                    + "<table>"
                    + output
                    + "</table>"
                    + "<button onclick='history.go(-1)' type='button'>Back</button>"
                    + "<button type='submit'>Create invoice</button>"
                    + "</form>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "</body>"
                    + "</html>";
            out.println(table);
            rs.close();
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**invoiceTable.jsp**  --- I wrote "???", because there must be data/values from table row which I selected. And I don't know which function or which parameter I must use.
`String Articles = request.getParameter("???");`

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Invoices</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%

            String sql;
            String output;
            String table;
            ResultSet rs;
            String Articles = request.getParameter("???");
            String Total_price = request.getParameter("???");
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/", "SA", "");

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

            sql = "INSERT INTO INVOICES (Articles, Total_price)"
                    + "VALUES( '" + Articles + "', '" + Total_price + "');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM INVOICES");

            output = "<tr><th>INVOICE NR.</th>" + "<th>ARTICLES</th>" + "<th>TOTAL PRICE</th></tr>";
            while (rs.next()) {
                output += "<tr><td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td>" + "<td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td>" + "<td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td></tr>";
            }
            table = "<html>"
                    + "<head>"
                    + "</head>"
                    + "<body>"
                    + "<div>"
                    + "<h1>Invoices</h1>"
                    + "<table>"
                    + output
                    + "</table>"
                    + "</form>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "</body>"
                    + "</html>";
            out.println(table);

            rs.close();
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to modify the following statement in productCatalog.jsp:

```
while (rs.next()){
    output += "<tr><td><input type='checkbox'></td>" + "<td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td>" + "<td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td>" + "<td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td></tr>";
}
```

to

```
int count=0;
while (rs.next()){
    output+="<tr>";
    output+="<td><input type='checkbox' name=row"+(count++)+" value="+rs.getString(1)+","+rs.getString(2)+","+rs.getString(3)+"></td>";
    output+="<td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td>"; 
    output+="<td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td>";
    output+="<td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td></tr>";
}
output+="<input type=hidden name='rowCount' value='"+count+"'>";
```

In invoiceTable.jsp, you can refer the following coding to extract the selected row data.

```
String article="";
String selectedRow;
String[] temp;
int totalPrice=0;
int rowCount = Integer.parse(request.getParameter("rowCount"));
if (rowCount>0){
    for (int i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
        selectedRow=request.getParameter("row"+i);
        if (selectedRow!=null){             //that mean the row is selected by user.
            temp=selectedRow.split(",");     //where temp[0]=product id,temp[1]=product name,temp[2]=product price.
            article+=temp[1]+" ";
            totalPrice+=Integer.parse(temp[2]); 
        }
    }
    .......................  //prepare your SQL statement and insert the data to the database.          
}
```

Comment: Typos in your code here `I<rowCount` ,`Interger`,`articel` .

Comment: @The KNVB thanks, it works very good, but, maybe, you know how can i sum price from selected products? Because, now, when I select two or more products and insert to invoice table, they are added separately from each other as invoice id 1 and 2, so I want them to be added to one order, for example ( Invoice id: 1, products: Ice Tea Hot Tea, total price: 21 ). If you know how I will be very grateful to you!

Comment: @The KNVB It works exactly as I wanted!!! Thank you!!!